# what is the reason behind the 401 error in node.js? please help I stuck on this

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the auth.js file I want to add the data but I am not doing this due to a 401 error in my in console`

```js
// Route#2 add the notes by using post method loggin required 
router.post('/addnote', fetchuser, [
  body('title', 'enter the valid name').isLength({
    min: 4
  }),

  body('description', 'The description must be letters less than 5 ').isLength({
    min: 4
  }),
], async(req, res) => {

  try {
    //  it is the javascript validation function->
    const {
      title,
      description,
      tag
    } = req.body
    // if there are errors then it will show the bad results
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }
    const note = new Notes({
      title,
      description,
      tag,
      user: req.user.id
    })
    const saveNote = await note.save()
    res.json(saveNote)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("some error occured")
  }

})
```

Comment: can you post the details of error in console.log ? thanks

Comment: Your code snippet is pretty difficult to read due to the inconsistent indentation. Can you format it a bit more consistently? It would also help to get more details about what frameworks you are using. 401s are authentication errors, I would expect there is some kind of authentication step happening before your routes are being invoked causing the 401.

Comment: bro i'm making a crud operation by using the MEARN

Comment: the upper code is belong to express.js